# changing the frame rate of an animated gif made in After Effects

Tags: gif, adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to export an animated gif from a 30fps comp in After Effects. Adobe Media Encoder won't offer the option of 30 for frame rate (just 1,2,4,5, 10,12.5,20,25,50).  I can't simply enter the value either.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Adobe Media Encoder can't export animated gifs can it?

Comment: Yes, it can. :-)

Comment: Apparently it's [Windows only](https://helpx.adobe.com/media-encoder/using/file-formats-supported-export.html#Stillimageandstillimagesequence) and I'm on Mac! I can tell you why though... I'll post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animated GIF frames have duration specified in hundredths of a second.

At 30fps each frame would be 0.033333333....

The frame rates you list there all correspond to frame length with only 2 decimal places. Which is all that is allowed. Theres no way around that as far as I'm aware.

Also, [according to this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/06/07/trivia-animated-gif-timing/) on the Microsoft developer blogs, some browsers will automatically slow down animated GIFs with a framerate of 20fps or more.